# Invalid source HTML for this operation error in ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs

I get

**SCRIPT601: Invalid source HTML for this operation.**

**ext-all-debug.js, line 6769 character 21**

in IE 8

This is the line.

```
el.insertAdjacentHTML(hashVal[0], html);
```

While debugging, the value in html is `"<a title=\"\">1</a>"`

I stuck with this issue for several days. This is related to a rating functionality. I think due to this error, the rating star is not displaying in ie 8. Other browsers are ok.
I have given the corresponding portion of code below. I am using extjs.

```
var starLink = star.createChild({
            tag: 'a',
            html: this.values[i],
            title: this.showTitles ? this.titles[i] : ''
        });
```

And while creating this element, the call will go to the following part and error occurs on the above specified line.

```
 insertHtml : function(where, el, html){
            var hash = {},
                hashVal,
                range,
                rangeEl,
                setStart,
                frag,
                rs;

            where = where.toLowerCase();

            hash[beforebegin] = ['beforeBegin', 'previousSibling'];
            hash[afterend] = ['afterEnd', 'nextSibling'];


            if (el.insertAdjacentHTML) {
                if(tableRe.test(el.tagName) && (rs = insertIntoTable(el.tagName.toLowerCase(), where, el, html))){
                    return rs;
                }


                hash[afterbegin] = ['afterBegin', 'firstChild'];
                hash[beforeend] = ['beforeEnd', 'lastChild'];
                if ((hashVal = hash[where])) {
                    el.insertAdjacentHTML(hashVal[0], html);
                    return el[hashVal[1]];
                }

            } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

IE is extremely fussy about using .innerHTML, .insertAdjacentHTML and similar.

The HTML passed must be *perfectly* structured - it does not allow any mistakes of any kind. If there are any, it won't do it at all. Other browsers will perform the same 'best guess' that they do on the rest of the document.

Try putting in something really simple as the HTML value like:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

And you should find it works. In which case you need to find what's wrong with the HTML you're supplying. If it doesn't work then you've got another problem.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please look into it once more?

Comment: Answer still applies. An `<a>` *requires* a `href=` otherwise it's not valid and IE will throw it away. Instead do something like `"<a title=\"\" href=\"javascript:void\">1</a>"` to have a valid link that does nothing.

Comment: I did it as u said. But still the same error `var starLink = star.createChild({
            tag: 'a',
            html: this.values[i],
            href: 'javascript:void',
            title: this.showTitles ? this.titles[i] : ''
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Though we don't know what elements you're creating and where, I assume you are trying to add a new `tr` element to the `table`. This however, is not possible in IE < 10. Older IEs have totally different table model from other browsers, and tables can't be accessed with `insertAdjacentHTML()` to create rows (`td`s can be created). Also `innerHTML` for direct descendants of `table` and `tr` is read-only.

The best way to add new rows to the table in IE is to use `insertRow(index)` method. `index` is the place where you want to add a row. By default `index` is -1, which adds a new row at the end of the table.

This article [Building Tables Dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN might be helpful.

BTW `if ((hashVal = hash[where]))` is not valid syntax in newer browsers anymore.

Comment: It is not a table. Instead nested divs

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please look into it once more?

Comment: @1355 I'm not familiar with extjs, but... Are you sure that this code you posted is the actual error source? (`ext-all-debug.js, line 6769 character 21`). IE devtools sometimes messes up with pointing to the correct errorline, even to the correct js file. Have you tested the code with other browsers?